# Вывести header на верх

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня есть header здесь  http://haydaybot2020.xyz/header/flex. При сжатии страницы срабатывает медиа запрос и появляется бургер с меню(которое в будущем будет открываться по бургеру). Как мне вывести header на верх меню (nav.header__menu)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Моя шапка 1</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?<? echo time();  ?>">
    <!-- Charset -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header__body">
                    <a href="" class="header__logo"><img src="img/logo_1.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="header__burger">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="header__menu">
                    <div class="header__list">
                        <a href="" class="header__link">
                            <span>Главная</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="" class="header__link">
                            <span>Портфолио</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="" class="header__link">
                            <span>Обо мне</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>


    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/*Обнуление*/
*,*:before,*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*Fonts*/
@font-face{
    font-family: "Bold";
    src: url(../fonts/FontsFree-Net-SFProDisplay-Bold.ttf)
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper.content{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    z-index: 2;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.header__body{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.header__logo{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.header__logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.header__link{
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.header__link span{
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-family: Bold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:deepskyblue;
}
.header__link:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 2s ease 0s;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out 0s;
    transform: scaleX(0.3) scaleY(0);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.header__link:hover:before{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
.header__list{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.header__burger{

}
.header__menu{
    height:100%;
}
@media(max-width: 550px){
        .header__burger{
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .header__burger:before,
    .header__burger:after{
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    .header__burger:before{
        top:0;
    }
        .header__burger:after{
        bottom:0;
    }

    .header__burger span{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 9px;
        background-color: #000;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;

    }

    .header__menu{
        z-index: 1;
    display:block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    }
    .header__list{
        display: block;
    
    }
    .header__link{
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    .header__link:first-child{
        margin: 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос не соответствует требованиям сайта. Приложите минимальный воспроизводимый код

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Если вы хотите, чтобы элемент отображался поверх всех остальных, задайте ему `z-index: 100` и он переместиться наверх. Или переформулируйте вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вывести ваш бургер с помощью позиционирования куда-угодно просто используя в CSS эти свойства: `position`, `top`, `left`, `right`,  `bottom`